# Dell iDRAC 8, how can I backup the server profile to vFlash without getting "OEMDRV partition is in use"?

Tags: dell-poweredge, drac

I'm preparing a PowerEdge T430 server for delivery to a customer. I wanted to configure automatic iDRAC/Lifecycle Manager profile backups onto the iDRAC vFlash card. When I try to perform a backup, it queues the job but it fails a few seconds later with the message:

> BAR109: OEMDRV partition is in use.

I don't really understand what is in use, or what I can do about it. The SD-Card is 8Gb and I have initialized it within the iDRAC menus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OEMDRV is a OS deployment driver virtual media exposed to the OS installer when launched with "Dell Lifecycle Controller" "OS Deploy" feature.

OEMDRV partition is automatically removed after 18 hours.

You cannot backup the XML server profile to the iDrac when this media is in use.

You can either wait until this partition is removed (18h) or force removal using this tip http://byronwright.blogspot.fr/2014/08/remove-oemdrv-drive-from-dell-server.html

Reference [here](http://www.dell.com/support/manuals/uk/en/ukdhs1/dell-opnmang-sw-v8.2/EEMI_13G_v1.3-v2/BAR-Event-Messages?guid=GUID-5567FBDF-2838-4641-B61A-E9A7034170E4&lang=en-us)

> **BAR109
>   Message**
>
> OEMDRV partition is in use.
>
> **Detailed Description**
>
> The OEMDRV partition is mounted for performing operating system deployment use. This situation prevents the Export and Import Server Profile operation from continuing.
>
> **Recommended Response Action**
>
> Dismount the OEMDRV partition by selecting F10 during boot and retry the operation.

Comment: I found that removing the VFLASH card from the UEFI boot order also worked.